# UnsatisfiedLinkError when using GvrLayout

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-vr

I'm developing a Google VR app with the NDK and my activity includes the following code:

```
if (gvrLayout.setAsyncReprojectionEnabled(true)) {
  AndroidCompat.setSustainedPerformanceMode(this, true);
}
```

This compiles, but when I try to run the app, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for 
  boolean com.google.vr.ndk.base.GvrApi.nativeUsingVrDisplayService(long) 
    (tried Java_com_google_vr_ndk_base_GvrApi_nativeUsingVrDisplayService 
     and Java_com_google_vr_ndk_base_GvrApi_nativeUsingVrDisplayService__J)                                                                                
  at com.google.vr.ndk.base.GvrApi.nativeUsingVrDisplayService(Native Method)
  at com.google.vr.ndk.base.GvrApi.usingVrDisplayService(SourceFile:952)
  at com.google.vr.ndk.base.GvrLayout.setAsyncReprojectionEnabled(SourceFile:610)
```

When I remove that section of code, the app runs without a problem. I'm including sdk-common-1.10.0.aar in my build. Do I need something else?